# Loop Over dictionary converting Json into SQL insert with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hi there i would like to loop over a dictionary that contains JSON arrays per line E.g.

```
For val in json_object:
    print(val)
```

produces:

```
[{'album': 'Led Zepplin 4', 'Artist': 'Led Zeplin', 'Time': 17:56.12, 'SongWriter': 'JimmyPage', 'Producer': None, 'Released': '1975-07-01'}, 
{'album': 'Led Zepplin 4', 'Artist': 'Led Zeplin', 'Time': 17:56.12, 'SongWriter': 'JimmyPage', 'Producer': None, 'Released': '1975-07-01'}, 
{'album': 'Led Zepplin 4', 'Artist': 'Led Zeplin', 'Time': 17:56.12, 'SongWriter': 'JimmyPage', 'Producer': None, 'Released': '1975-07-01', 'AlbumArtist': 'ajsfa'}]
```

I would like to create a list of INSERT statements for each line. Sometimes AlbumArtist appears sometimes it doesnt. If it didnt thats fine it can be NULL

```
INSERT INTO MusicTest ([album], [Artist], [Time], [SongWriter], [Producer], [Released], [AlbumArtist]) VALUES ();
```

Ive tried writing my own python piece which normally works fine:

```
def extract_values(obj, key):
    """Pull all values of specified key from nested JSON."""
    arr = []

    def extract(obj, arr, key):
        """Recursively search for values of key in JSON tree."""
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for k, v in obj.items():
                if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                    extract(v, arr, key)
                elif k == key:
                    arr.append(v)
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for item in obj:
                extract(item, arr, key)
        return arr

    results = extract(obj, arr, key)
    return results
```

To be used like:

```
    for val in json_object:
        print(val)
        name = extract_values(val.json(), "name")
        print(name)
```

But i keep getting the error:
'dict' object has no attribute 'json' at: name = extract_values(val.json(), "name")

any ideas?

I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975479/parsing-json-into-insert-statements-with-python):

```
    for json in r:
        keylist = "("
        valuelist="("
        firstPair = True
        for attribute, value in json.items():
            if not firstPair:
                keylist += ", "
                valuelist += ", "
            firstPair = False
            keylist += key
            if type(value) in (str, unicode):
                valuelist += "'" + value + "'"
            else:
                valuelist += str(value)
        keylist += ")"
        valuelist += ")"
        sqlstatement += "INSERT INTO IMPORTTABLE " + keylist + " VALUES " + valuelist + "\n"
        print(sqlstatement)
```

But get the error 'str' object has no attribute 'items' at for attribute, value in json.items():

Comment: r is just the variable holding the JSON as show in the answer of the hyperlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please chek this.

```
data_dict_lis = [{'album': 'Led Zepplin 4', 'Artist': 'Led Zeplin', 'Time': "17:56.12", 'SongWriter': 'JimmyPage', 'Producer': None, 'Released': '1975-07-01'},
{'album': 'Led Zepplin 4', 'Artist': 'Led Zeplin', 'Time': "17:56.12", 'SongWriter': 'JimmyPage', 'Producer': None, 'Released': '1975-07-01'},
{'album': 'Led Zepplin 4', 'Artist': 'Led Zeplin', 'Time': "17:56.12", 'SongWriter': 'JimmyPage', 'Producer': None, 'Released': '1975-07-01', 'AlbumArtist': 'ajsfa'}]



for data_dict in data_dict_lis:
    table_keys = ",".join([key for key in data_dict.keys()])
    table_values = ",".join([str(value) for value in data_dict.values()])

    sql = "INSERT INTO IMPORTTABLE ("+table_keys+") VALUES ("+table_values+")"
    print(sql)
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna thats really helped.